# Expo google login redirect to google home page

Tags: android, expo, google-signin

I am trying to add google sign-in feature to my app. This is working fine with an android emulator but I am running the app in the real device it is not working. The problem is after the sign-in process google redirect to its own home page instead to app.

The step I follow.

Function I use to open google sign in page

```
const result = await Google.logInAsync({
  androidStandaloneAppClientId: '131814552849-bi76mebb3eq5jsdergerdfh6werjd8udpen43.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  behavior: 'web
});
```

app.json

I used Google Certificate Hash (SHA-1) in certificateHash

```
 "android": {
   "package": "com.abc.mycompnay",
   "permissions": ["READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
   "config": {
     "googleSignIn": {
       "apiKey": "AIzaSyB6qp9VXGXrtwuihvna40F57xABKXJfEQ",
       "certificateHash": "29FD8B159A28F2F48ED3283548NEBFC957F6821D"
     }
   }
 }
```

> google console setting

[image]

**Client key**

[image]

After sign in its end up with its own home page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix it. below is what I did. I pass the redirectUrl in config

```
import * as AppAuth from 'expo-app-auth';

const result = await Google.logInAsync({
  androidStandaloneAppClientId: 'myKey,
  iosStandaloneAppClientId: 'myKey,
  scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  behavior: 'web',
  redirectUrl: `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect`
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me where the url come from? I want to do it on my app but i dont understand what to wrote inside 
  redirectUrl: `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect

Comment: My package is "com.roei.app.com"

Comment: LIFE SAVER! Thank you so much mate! (after more than 3 hours I found this finally)

Answer (score 1):

In app.json,
package name has to be as all small letters like com.app.cloneapp

Answer (score 0):

Open the gradle and change the redirect scheme

```
android {
defaultConfig {
manifestPlaceholders = [
  appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.example.yourpackagename'
]
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not have access to gradle file. It an expo app

Comment: @Carlos It's a platform-dependent scenario. I am afraid that you have to eject from expo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll put this here since this cost me a ton of lifetime. If you happen to test it with an Android device: Make sure you have selected Chrome as default browser. Others might not redirect you correctly!